# Bubble Sorting in c

Tags: c, sorting

plz tell me the mistake.
Its running perfectly but no operations is performed on the array. Don't know why...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void BubbleSort(int a[],int size){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<(size-1);i++){
         for(j=0;j<(size-i-1);j++){
               if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    int temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
          }
     }
}
void main(){
     int a[]={2,5,8,4,6,7,9,1,3};
     int size=9;
     BubbleSort(a,size);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
     printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: line 7 in your BubbleSort function should be `a[j+1]=temp;` and not `a[j]=temp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong data swapping:

```
int temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[j+1];
a[j]=temp; //you assign the same data that a[j] held before
```

should be:

```
int temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[j+1];
a[j+1]=temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           //the swapping of value should be like this:
           if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                int temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
```